# Column alias LINQ Query

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a Query like this, where I want to union these two queries. But union condition is both results from two tables must have same column name, so GroupName has to be retrieved, but it has to be aliased as Type1 in this Query.

```
var vTLst = (from t in db.Types select t.Type1).Union
            (from g in db.Groups select g.GroupName).ToList().Distinct();
```

Help me out please...

Comment: It should work, do you get any errors? What column types are `Type1` and `GroupName`?

Comment: Just a note: for efficiency you should run `.Distinct()` before `.ToList()` to have the database doing the `Distinct` before sending the result to the client.

Answer (score 0):

That is wrong, if `t.Type1` and `g.GroupName` are columns and of the same type your query should work. The result will just be `IQueryable<string>` or whatever column type you have, no anonymous type with names or anything.

If you have a more complex query with more columns or anonymous types you can use column aliases.

```
var vTLst = (from t in db.Types select new {Col1 = t.Type1, Col2 = t.Type2}).Union
            (from g in db.Groups select new {Col1 = g.GroupName, Col2 = g.Col2})
            .ToList().Distinct();
```

If your problem is that the columns are not of the same type you can convert them to the same type

```
var vTLst = (from t in db.Types select t.Type1.ToString()).Union
            (from g in db.Groups select g.GroupName.ToString()).ToList().Distinct();
```

Comment: SELECT Type1 FROM Types UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT GroupName AS Type1 FROM Groups              This is my Query, working fine in Query Analyzer. Could you please convert this to LINQ Query.